# What is the best way to display the bottom border on heading tag?

Tags: html, css

I have three paragraphs with heading and each heading have a border-bottom which is on the left side.

I used `h2:after{//CSS here }` to display the border. I used `left: 13.5%;` for the first heading to display the border on the left side.I can use the left:25% for second and left:39% for the last heading to display the border but I know this is not a good way to display. Because If I used to like this then I have to use the media query for all the device to set the border.

I want to know which is the best way to use the border-bottom and all are display on the left side.

**Getting the output**
[image]

**I need a output**

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.heading {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.heading h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading h2 span {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.heading h2:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  left: 13.5%;
  transform: translateX(-13.5%);
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="par_1">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_2">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum</span>dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_3">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>dolor sit amet</span></h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply it to the span instead of the h2 and no need to specify a specific value to left, simply make it 0 and also bottom to 0 (or any negative value if you want it to be lower)

*[don't forget `position:relative` on span]*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.heading {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.heading h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading h2 span {
  color: #0000ff;
  position:relative;
}

.heading h2 span:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="par_1">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_2">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum</span>dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_3">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>dolor sit amet</span></h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal i know, and where you see a full length ? :) i kept the same style as him and i have the same output as his screenshot

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I copied your code but I am not getting the same output. I am getting the border on the top of the heading.

Comment: @Hybreeder you added postion relative to span ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes I applied. I am sharing the screenshot if the output http://prntscr.com/i1kdzo

Comment: @Hybreeder add bottom:0 also

Comment: Yes, This time it's working perfectly. Thanks @TemaniAfif. Update your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `pseudo element :after` in your `span` because it covers the exact width of your heading text. Then you should give your span a relative positioning so it will become its parent. Then just give it a 0% left positioning so it will align with the left. Your code should look like this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.heading {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.heading h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading h2 span {
  color: #0000ff;
  position: relative;
}

.heading h2 span:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid #E43D32;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="par_1">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_2">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum</span>dolor sit amet</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="par_3">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2><span>dolor sit amet</span></h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```